# What is the difference between IQ mixers and normal mixers?

Tags: mixer

What is the difference between IQ mixers and multiplication mixers? How do we know which ones to use?

Comment: IQ mixer is a mixer that is attended by a lot of mensa members  ... lol ... i just could not help myself

Comment: I only have a glancing knowledge, so perhaps this waits for someone better. My experience is with Gilbert (he died, this year) double-balanced mixers and IQ mixers formed from two of these, attenuating the carrier and one of the sidebands -- so largely for SSB modulation. So I think of IQ mixers as made up of two double balanced mixers.

Comment: https://www.markimicrowave.com/blog/the-why-and-when-of-iq-mixers-for-beginners/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwgo_5BRDuARIsADDEntQa94VlcNAKBqIFQvG9sXVQ7UtkvhzPVTqIthjBYiqDR1x8q2OseocaAlzmEALw_wcB